# PHP pcntl_wait() does not wait for child exit

Tags: php, fork, wait

I have a php script that forks and parent calls pnctl_wait(). According to php manual pcntl_wait() should suspend execution of the current process until a child has exited. But this does not happen. 
The parent process does not wait at all and executes the next line immediately.

I have tried to replicate the issue in a small sample script below

```
<?php
$parentpid=getmypid();
declare(ticks=1);
$apid = pcntl_fork();
if ($apid == -1) {
  die('could not fork for client '.$client);
 } else if ($apid) {     //parent                                                                                                              


pcntl_wait($status,WNOHANG); //Protect against Zombie children                                                                     
/* Parent does not wait here */ 

  print "PARENT $parentpid has forked $apid \n";   

  sleep(100);
 } else { // child                                                                                                                             
  $pid = getmypid();
  print "CHILD $pid  is sleeping\n";
  sleep(40);
 }


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want the option `WNOHANG` here. Just use:

```
pcntl_wait($status);
```

If you pass `WNOHANG` `pcntl_wait()` will not wait for children to return. It only reports childs which *have already been terminated*.

---

The whole example should look like this:

```
$parentpid = getmypid();
$apid = pcntl_fork();

if ($apid == -1) {
  die('could not fork for client '.$client);
} else if ($apid) {
    // Parent process
    print "PARENT $parentpid has forked $apid \n";

    // Wait for children to return. Otherwise they 
    // would turn into "Zombie" processes
    pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
  // Child process
  $pid = getmypid();
  print "CHILD $pid  is sleeping\n";
  sleep(40);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, pcntl in php functions will not work on apache server running,  So PHP don't support child processes like other languages such as fork in C++.